# execution failure of an self insertion_sort definition in python3

Tags: python

I want to put the numbers from the smallest to the largest.

NO.1  succeed

```
def insertion_sort(list):
    for index in range(1,len(list)):
        value = list[index]
        i = index-1
        while i >=0:
            if value < list[i]:
                list[i+1]=list[i]
                list[i] = value
                i = i-1
            else :
                break
a=[2,1,4,3,6,7,9,5]
insertion_sort(a)
print(a)
```

NO.2 failed

```
def insertion_sort(list):
    for index in range(1,len(list)):
        value = list[index]
        i = index - 1
        while i>=0:
            if value > list[i]:
                i=i-1

            else :
                list[i+1]=list[i]
                list[i]=value
            break


a=[1,3,2,7,4,6,5]
insertion_sort(a)
print(a)
```

when I ran the second, it returned `[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7]`

I don't know why and if I remove `break`, in the second one, it won't return a result, why? I thought the for loop will close itself.

Comment: Why don't you use `sorted` or `np.sort()` ?

Comment: `break`is not well indented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementation of insertion sort (without sentinel) should look like;

```
def insertion_sort(list_):
    for index in range(1,len(list_)):
        value = list_[index]
        i = index - 1
        while i >= 0 and list_[i] > value :
             list_[i + 1] = list_[i]
             list_[i] = value
             i = i - 1
    return list_
```

Also remember to not named your list argument `list` because it's python builtin class.